# Logs not available for attempt, could by caused by the retention policy

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

When I want to see logs for completed or killed workflow job created in Oozie by Hue Job Editor (Hortonworks) only what I get is message:

```
Logs not available for attempt [...]. Could be caused by the rentention policy.
```

This message is for every type of logs: stdout, stderr, syslog, for every kind of workflow jobs (Pig, Fs, Shell).

Did someone have the same issue? Thanks for help.

Comment: Try using Oozie CLI, e.g.: `oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -info 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe` It will give you a job ID like job_1416887695995_403293. Then try finding this job in your job tracker.

Comment: Ok, but how can I fix this error in Hue?

Comment: From my experience, the integration of Oozie in Hue in HDP, or CDH is not great. That is why I suggest using Oozie CLI.